# apt-get update start to fail since last Friday

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

On my ubuntu host, When I was to run the apt-get update command, I am starting to get such failure since 05/06/2022.  And it was working perfectly fine before.

Any idea what may have triggered such failure ?

Thanks.

Jack

```
apt-get update
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease [66.2 kB]
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 216.58.194.206 80]
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial/stable amd64 Packages [21.0 kB]
...
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
...
Ign:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
  403  Forbidden
Ign:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Fetched 28.6 MB in 16s (1,720 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 216.58.194.206 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/i18n/Translation-en  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors: The apt-translation and the Google repository.

Disable the translation:

```
echo "Acquire::Languages { "none"; };" |sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Then disable (temporary) the Google repository in your `sources.list`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain the root cause of such failure ? Why it was working before ?

Comment: @user3595231 It can be a temporary failure in google repository. Also, the translation during `apt update` may fail. You can enable the google repository again later.